# Where is Main Street of Jurassic World located?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

In the 2015 blockbuster sequel, Jurassic World, Where is the Main Hub of Jurassic World located?

Comment: What do you mean by "*two answers are acceptable*," you can define your requirements for an "acceptable" answer, but you don't get to demand, or specify, the number of answers you receive. If you receive *any* (though you almost certainly will, if the question is considered worthwhile/on-topic).

Comment: It sounds as if you already know the answer to this question. Please be aware that, while they are not strictly off-topic, asking questions to which you know the answer and want to "test" other users does somewhat violate the spirit of this site (and most other SE sites)

Comment: It's on Isla Nublar

Answer (score 4):

The main hub is located at the [lagoon entrance](http://i2.wp.com/www.slashfilm.com/wp/wp-content/images/Rumor-Jurassic-World-Map-6.jpg), approximately 5 miles to the east of the site of the original Jurassic Park '[Visitor Centre](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/jurassicpark/images/6/60/Jptourmap2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120609001824)' on Isla Nublar (itself situated some 120 miles off the west coast of Costa Rica)

[image]

There's an interactive map on the official [Jurassic World](http://www.jurassicworld.com/park-map/) website where you can learn more about the park and its attractions as well as buying tickets to the park itself <sub><sup>(facility currently disabled)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3):

## In universe

Jurassic World is located on Isla Nublar - the same island as the original Jurassic Park.

[image]

## Out of universe

While much of the filming took place in Hawaii, the Main Street set of Jurassic World was built at an abandoned Six Flags theme park in New Orleans.

> A little background on the theme park itself: Six Flags New Orleans was abandoned after the fallout of Hurricane Katrina devastated the park and left it unfit for operation. Since 2011, filmmakers have used the site of the former amusement for filming purposes. Most recently, Fox films like Percy Jackson: Sea Of Monsters (shown above) and Dawn Of The Planet Of The Apes have shot some material on the grounds, and studios have even been in talks with the city of New Orleans to lease out the land for future productions. Films like Jurassic World have a great location to film scenes of devastation and desolation, and the local economy is rewarded with an opportunity to make money off of a unique landscape.
> <sub>- [CinemaBlend](http://www.cinemablend.com/m/new/Jurassic-World-Start-Filming-An-Abandoned-Six-Flags-43306.html)</sub>

[image]

[image]